# Unicorn & Heroku - is a different configuration for each dyno possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque, sidekiq

I'm currently running my app on 2 Heroku dynos. From what I've looked up so far I need to add something similar to config/unicorn.rb:

```
worker_processes 3
timeout 30

@resque_pid = nil

before_fork do |server, worker|
  @resque_pid ||= spawn("bundle exec rake " + \
  "resque:work QUEUES=scrape,geocode,distance,mailer")
end
```

I have a few different background jobs to process, some need to be run single-threaded and some concurrently. The problem with this configuration is that on both Unicorn instances it will spawn exactly the same resque worker (same queues etc).

It would greatly simplify everything if I could change the type of queues each worker processes - or even have one instance running a resque worker and the other a sidekiq worker.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are confusing unicorn worker_processes and Heroku workers?

you can use your Procfile to start Heroku workers for each queue and a unicorn process for handling web requests.

try this setup

/config/unicorn.rb

```
worker_processes 4 # amount of unicorn workers to spin up
timeout 30         # restarts workers that hang for 30 seconds
```

/Procfile

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
worker: bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUES=scrape,geocode,distance,mailer
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The thing is with the above setup you only pay for 1 dyno (1 is free), but get 6 web processes + 2 workers. See here: http://bugsplat.info/2011-11-27-concurrency-on-heroku-cedar.html With your setup would each worker count as a separate dyno you need to pay for?